# Postgres: I set log_hostname on but still client_hostname is null in pg_stat_activity

Tags: postgresql

I have this problem with Postgres.

I need to get the `client_hostname from pg_stat_activity`. I set `log_hostname=on` on the server but still `client_hostname` is null in `pg_stat_activity`.

What am I missing?

Comment: According to the documentation this field is only non null when log_hostname is on and it is an IP connection. Is client_addr populated with an IP?

Comment: Did you restart Postgres? Reloading the configuration is not enough

Comment: I face the same problem. set the `log_hostname ON` and restart the server. and it's still null when I see it using `pg_stat_activity`